# Remove quotes when reading from sessionStorage and sending to php using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sessionstorage

I'm storing different values in the sessionStorage during a longer process. At the end i want to read all the data and send it to my php  backend using ajax. The problem is that php seems to take every value including quotes. Here is what i got:

```
// Reading data from storage
var imgb = sessionStorage.getItem("img_b_id");
....
// perpare data
var oData = {
            imgb: imgb,
            ...
};

// Sending data
$.post( "../php/direct/create.php", oData).done(function(data) {
    if(data==true) {
        window.open("step5.php", "_self");
    } else {
        alert("Error: " + data.toString()); 
    }
});
```

This is working perfectly fine. However, php will read the value of imbg **with** quotes. Example:

```
echo $_POST['imgb'];
/* Returns "asd" instead of asd
```

The image below shows that my data is stored without the quotes (chrome sessionstorage screenshot)
[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this. I currently replace the quotes, but I'd love to fix this problem at it's root...

Comment: Why not store/send data as JSON string?

Comment: Shoud  imgb: **imbg** be imgb: **imgb**?

Comment: yeah of course - sry imbg = imgb in the actual code. How and why should i send it as json string? as said the actual data is way more and consists of many redirects, page links etc. my only problem are the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code ( with Firefox and Chrome ) and

```
echo $_POST['imgb'];
```

Print the string without quotes.
Consider that even if you set a number in the session storage, for example

```
sessionStorage.setItem("img_b_id", 100);
```

The value is received at server by PHP as a string so you can convert it with PHP functions intval(), floatval() etc.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php